# Add cancel button on progress dialog

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, progressdialog

I am trying to enable the Cancel button on the `ProgressDialog` in Xamarin Android, but it doesn't appear.

This is what I did until now:

```
ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(Context);
progressDialog.SetProgressStyle(ProgressDialogStyle.Horizontal);
progressDialog.SetCancelable(true);

progressDialog.CancelEvent += (o, e) =>
{
    // Cancel download
};

progressDialog.Show();
```

Related questions: [How to set cancel button in Progress Dialog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7037433/how-to-set-cancel-button-in-progress-dialog) or [Android ProgressDialog can't add Cancel button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15293146/android-progressdialog-cant-add-cancel-button)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note: `ProgressDialog` is now `deprecated` in API-26

```
var progress = new ProgressDialog(this);
progress.SetTitle("Syncing Events");
progress.Indeterminate = false;
progress.SetProgressStyle(ProgressDialogStyle.Horizontal);
progress.Max = totalEvents;
progress.Progress = currentEvent;
progress.SetButton(-3, "CancelLeft", (sender, e) => {
    Log.Debug("SO", "Cancel");
});
progress.SetButton(-2, "CancelMiddle", (sender, e) =>
{
    Log.Debug("SO", "Cancel");
});
progress.SetButton(-1, "CancelRight", (sender, e) =>
{
    Log.Debug("SO", "Cancel");
});
progress.Show();
```

[image]

Comment: This is an even better answer

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it the following way:

```
progressDialog.SetButton("Cancel", new EventHandler<DialogClickEventArgs>(
    (s, args) => { 
        // Cancel download
    }
));
```

Comment: FYI: That SetButton method has been deprecated since API  3, use the SetButton method that accepts an `int` (`whichButton`) as the first parameter

Answer (score 0):

```
ProgressDialog myDialog = new ProgressDialog(YourActivity.this);
myDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
myDialog.setCancelable(false);
myDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
});
myDialog.show();
```

Comment: This is Java. I was asking about Xamarin/C#.